# css class dynamic

Tags: css, angular, dynamic

I want to set color to a text dynamically based on data I retrieve from backend. For example if the response is:

```
 "names": [
            {
                "name": "apple",
            },
            {
                "name": "banana",
            },
```

I want to have red color on text apple, yellow on text banana. 
How can I give color to this text dynamically?

Here's my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of names">
    <span>{{data.name}}</span>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
  getData() {
    this.http.get('**')
      .subscribe(data => {
      });
  }
```

Comment: How's your HTML?

Comment: Use the ngClass directive. If you can paste your HTML code, or component, that can be modified to show how it is done. ngClass should get it done for you.

Comment: First you should have somewhere a [configuration / object / dictionary / replace by anything suitable] that maps your names to some actual CSS class of your application. Then you apply the corresponding class on the element containing the text, like a span. To give you more details, we need more details from your part.

Comment: i edited the question @bugs

Comment: Would it not be best to just serve the color or a css class from your backend, then you could fruits to colors in your backend/database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
color = ["red", "green", ..];

<div *ngFor="let data of names;let i=index">
    <span [style.color]="color[i]">{{data.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I initialized an array color like you said and tried. It is saying cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It will be quite similar to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of names ;let i = index">
<h6 *ngIf="i%2 == 0" style="color: red" >{{data.name}}</h6>
<h6 *ngIf="i%2 != 0" style="color: yellow" >{{data.name}}</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: I won't be having the same names. The data may vary. To be more specific I want the first name to be in red, second in yellow.

Comment: ok..Do you have only two data in your array or the number is not fixed?

Comment: I will have 10.

Comment: ok..you can use index for that..even will be in red , odd in yellow..modified the code

Comment: I will have 10 names and 10 colors.

Comment: First clearly write your requirements ..else difficult to provide proper answer. You have nowhere mentioned what is the condition to assign the colors against the names. So be specific what you want..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169697/discussion-between-yer-and-rak2018).